# How to avoid "Input system error. The system is being restarted"

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

Folks,

I have an EditField. When i try to enter any character, it throws java.lang.IllegalStateException. If I then continue, the OS says "Input system error. The system is being restarted". I saw at [BlackBerry Java Development Environment Version 4.2.0 
Release Notes and Known Issues List](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/638/Release_Notes_and_Known_Issues_List.pdf) link that it is a known error. Is there anything that I can do in my app to avoid this from happening.

I am testing this on a Blackberry 9860 (7.0.0.440)

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue. No work around as of yet.